# How do I know when the user clicked the TButtonedEdit.OnRightButton?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am building (in Delphi XE7) a custom control based on TGroupBox.
It contains among other controls a TButtonedEdit.

```
constructor TMyControl.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
VAR myIcon: TIcon;
begin
 inherited Create(aOwner);
 ...
 edtPath:= TButtonedEdit.Create(Self);
 WITH edtPath DO
  begin
   Parent                := Self;
   RightButton.Glyph.OnClick:= MyOwnHandler;      <- Here error: "Cannot access protected symbol TEditButton.Glyph"
   RightButton.OnRightButtonClick:= MyOwnHandler; <- Here error: "Undeclared identifier: 'OnRightButtonClick'"
  end;
end;
```

How do I know when the user pressed the RightButton?

GetOnRightButtonClick and SetOnRightButtonClick are private. 
The same for RightButton.Glyph.OnClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to access `RightButton` or anything beyond the control itself. Just assign your event handler directly to `TButtonedEdit.OnRightButtonClick`. Any events you find within the control's properties are only intended to be used internally by the control itself. These events are not published, and therefore you shouldn't try to use them.

```
WITH edtPath DO
begin
  Parent                := Self;
  OnRightButtonClick:= MyOwnHandler;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Jerry. It also won't work. I get:  "Undeclared identifier: 'OnRightButtonClick'"

Comment: @SolarWind Look in your Object Inspector for one of these `TButtonedEdit` controls. Specifically the events. Do you see such an event `OnRightButtonClick`?

Comment: Yes. I actually see it! I also see the OnLeftButtonClick.

Comment: @SolarWind Then it should work. I see no reason why you should be getting an Undeclared Identifier error.

Comment: @SolarWind Your edit in your question is still trying to access this event through the `RightButton` property. Get rid of `RightButton` in your code. Same with `Glyph`, you're not supposed to be trying to access that.

Comment: Your edit also changed your Title away from the correct answer. You had already answered your own question in the original title. Now for some reason your title is referring to something which doesn't even exist.